# Display a text field with dropdown box choosen

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm trying to get the form to display the text field after a dropdown option is chosen.

So when the option **other** is chosen, the input field will be **displayed** and become **required**.

```js
function chooseOther()
{
    var option = document.getElementById("inputJob");
    if (option == 'Other'){
        var field = document.getElementById("inputOtherJob");
        field.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

```html
<p> What is your profession? </p>
<select id="inputJob" name="inputJob" onchange = 'chooseOther()'>
  <option value="Student">Student</option>
  <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<input id = "inputOtherJob" name = "inputOtherJob" style = 'display: none'>
```

Comment: You've forgot to get the value: `var option = document.getElementById("inputJob").value;`

Answer (score 0):

**option.selectedOptions[0].text** for displaying the selected text.

Use attribute required to make it required.

```
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(option.value == 'Other')`, you must compare `option.value` not `option` because option is the `instanceof HTMLElement` so you must get its `value`.

```js
function chooseOther()
{
    var option = document.getElementById("inputJob");
    if (option.value == 'Other'){
        var field = document.getElementById("inputOtherJob");
        field.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

```html
<p> What is your profession? </p>
<select id="inputJob" name="inputJob" onchange = 'chooseOther()'>
  <option value="Student">Student</option>
  <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<input id = "inputOtherJob" name = "inputOtherJob" style = 'display: none'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix. Primarily you want to test against option.value == 'Other' rather than option == 'Other'

```js
<select id="inputJob" name="inputJob" onchange='chooseOther()'>
    <option value="Student">Student</option>
    <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<input id="inputOtherJob" name="inputOtherJob" style='display: none'>
<script>
    function chooseOther() {
        var option = document.getElementById("inputJob");
        if (option.value == 'Other') {
            var field = document.getElementById("inputOtherJob");
            field.setAttribute("style","display:inline");
        }
    }
</script>
```